# Quickest way to obtain just the document id from this string

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a string in my database in this form:

Deletion of document Id 234713. Source: 'CPS (Multi)'. PTS: '413'. Batch Id: '23/04/2008 3:37:14 PM WKS01011364'.

Deletion of document Id 234714. Source: 'CPS (Multi)'. PTS: '413'. Batch Id: '23/04/2008 3:37:14 PM WKS01011364'.

Deletion of document Id 235168. Source: 'CPS (Multi)'. PTS: '944'. Batch Id: '23/04/2008 3:37:14 PM WKS01011364'.

Deletion of document Id 235888. Source: 'CPS (Multi)'. PTS: '808'. Batch Id: '23/04/2008 3:37:14 PM WKS01011364'.

Deletion of document Id 237296. Source: 'CPS (Multi)'. PTS: '944'. Batch Id: '23/04/2008 3:37:14 PM WKS01011364'.

This table will have many thousands of rows, And I am looking for the best way to obtain just the Document ID (ie 234713, 234714 etc) in a select statement.

I Have this so far

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(notes, '\d{6}') as Doc_id
FROM   table
WHERE  TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(notes, '\d{6}')) > 0;
```

Comment: Are you guaranteed that the string will start "Deletion of document Id " and then a 6 digit number followed by a period?  If so, it's a pretty trivial `substr` since you want the same 6 positions every time.  My guess, though, is that your actual data isn't quite so regular in which case you'll need to tell us what we can assume about the structure of the data.

Comment: yes the structure will also be the same

Comment: Then it sounds like you just want `substr(notes,24,6)` if my ability to count letters is correct.